# get precipitation time series for the grid cell closest to a chosen station (loop over all)

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

I am pretty new with Python and I need some help. 
I need to find the grid cells in the precipitation file (.nc) that matches the locations of water flow stations (excel file) and then extract time series for these grid cells.

I have a Exel file with 117 stations in Norway that contains columns with station name and their areal, latitude and longitude. 
I also have a nc file with precipitation series for this stations.

I manage to run a python script (Jupyter notebook) for on station at a time, but want to run it for all stations. 
How do i do this? I know I need to make a for loop some how.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import os
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy as cy
metapath = "Minestasjoner.xlsx" 
rrdatapath = "cropped_monsum_rr_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_v20.0e.nc" 
meta = pd.read_excel(metapath)
rrdata = xr.open_dataset(rrdatapath)
i=0
station = meta.iloc[i]["Regime"]*100000 + meta.iloc[i]["Main_nr"]
lon = meta.iloc[i]["Longitude"] #get longitude
lat = meta.iloc[i]["Latitude"] #get latitude
rr_at_obsloc = rrdata["rr"].sel(latitude=lat, longitude=lon, method='nearest') 
df = rr_at_obsloc.to_dataframe() 
print("Station %s with lon=%.2f and lat=%.2f have closest rr gridcell at lon=%.2f and lat=%.2f"%(station,lon,lat,df.longitude[0],df.latitude[0]))
df
```

Comment: Hey @madelen, did the answer below solve your problem? :)

Comment: If so, please accept it

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way for you to do this is to make a python `dictionary` containing the station name and precipitation time-series for that station, and then to convert that dictionary to a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Here's how you do that in a simple loop:

```py
"""
Everything you had previously...
"""

# Initialize empty dictionary to hold station names and time-series
station_name_and_data = {}

# Loop over all stations
for i in range(117):
    # Get name of station 'i'
    station = meta.iloc[i]["Regime"]*100000 + meta.iloc[i]["Main_nr"]

    # Get lat/lon of station 'i'
    lon = meta.iloc[i]["Longitude"] 
    lat = meta.iloc[i]["Latitude"] 

    # Extract precip time-series for this lat-lon
    rr_at_obsloc = rrdata["rr"].sel(latitude=lat, longitude=lon, method='nearest')

    # Put this station name and it's relevant time-series into a dictionary 
    station_name_and_data[station]=rr_at_obsloc

# Finally, convert this dictionary to a pandas dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=station_name_and_data)

print(df)
```